# Why is this not a string?

Tags: python, string

I'm working my way through "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" by Al Sweigart (great read so far!).

Could someone kindly explain this line of code to me:

```
print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')
```

So this line is used in a while loop and results in the following being printed:

> Jimmy Five Times (0)
>
> Jimmy Five Times (1)
>
> Jimmy Five Times (2)
>
> Jimmy Five Times (3)
>
> Jimmy Five Times (4)

Thats great but reading the code I would have expected this to print just once:

> Jimmy Five Times ( + str(i) + )

Why are the contents of the bracket not converted to a string when the code in question is encapsulated by ' ' ? Whats more, the nested brackets also convert to a string, which I would expect to happen, but clearly its function appears to be to evaluate its contents first...and I figured it out. I'm going to leave this up here in case anyone else is wondering:

```
Print(
```

*First string:* `'Jimmy Five Times ('`

```
+ str(i) +
```

*Second string:* `')'`

```
)
```

Comment: The function str() is executed. Try print('Jimmy Five Times ( + str(' + i + ') + )').

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple string addition :

```
second_string = 'second string'
print ('first string'+str(second_string)+'third string as a bracket'
```

in your case:
first string is: 'Jimmy Five Times ('
second string is: str(i)
and third string is: ')'

Since Python 3.6 implement f-string we should use cleaner and easier to read version:

```
print (f'Jimmy Five Times ({i})')
```

Comment: Thats brilliant thank you! I just tried it with an f-string and read up on the same. Very nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

To print the same you could also do:

```
print('Jimmy Five Times ({})'.format(str(i)))
#or
print(f'Jimmy Five Times ({str(i)})')
```

Whatever code is inside the curly brackets will be executed and inserted into the string, however, it's important not to forget the `f"{}"` at the start, otherwise this won't work

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the quotation marks incorrectly. Below shows the first and second block of quotes which results in the correct code executing as shown in the book:

```
Print(
```

*First string:* `'Jimmy Five Times ('`

```
+ str(i) +
```

*Second string:* `')'`

```
)
```